# Notification Issue (Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, notifications

I'm studying notifications and service and I'm trying to send a notification to the system when I click in a button to activate the service.
It's a simple test for my studying.
Anyone can help me?

Below the setOnClickListener code:

```
Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(ExemploIniciarServico.this, 0, new Intent(ExemploIniciarServico.this,ExemploIniciarServico.class), 0);
            NotificationCompat.Builder buider = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ExemploIniciarServico.this);
            buider.setTicker("Teste de servidor");
            buider.setContentTitle("Informação");
            buider.setContentText("O serviço esta rodando.");
            buider.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            buider.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            //buider.setContentIntent(pi);

            Notification n = buider.build();
            n.vibrate= new long[]{150,300,150,600};
            nm.notify(R.drawable.ic_launcher,n);
            startService(it);

        }
```

This is the error log:

10-01 02:47:58.195: E/AndroidRuntime(361): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentIntent required: pkg=br.com.livroandroid.serviceteste id=2130837591 notification=Notification(vibrate=[150,300,150,600],sound=null,defaults=0x0)
10-01 02:47:58.195: E/AndroidRuntime(361):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1251)
10-01 02:47:58.195: E/AndroidRuntime(361):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
10-01 02:47:58.195: E/AndroidRuntime(361):     at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:274)
10-01 02:47:58.195: E/AndroidRuntime(361):     at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:110)
10-01 02:47:58.195: E/AndroidRuntime(361):     at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:90)
10-01 02:47:58.195: E/AndroidRuntime(361):     at br.com.livroandroid.serviceteste.ExemploIniciarServico$1.onClick(ExemploIniciarServico.java:44)
10-01 02:47:58.195: E/AndroidRuntime(361):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
10-01 02:47:58.195: E/AndroidRuntime(361):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
10-01 02:47:58.195: E/AndroidRuntime(361):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-01 02:47:58.195: E/AndroidRuntime(361):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-01 02:47:58.195: E/AndroidRuntime(361):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-01 02:47:58.195: E/AndroidRuntime(361):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-01 02:47:58.195: E/AndroidRuntime(361):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 02:47:58.195: E/AndroidRuntime(361):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-01 02:47:58.195: E/AndroidRuntime(361):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-01 02:47:58.195: E/AndroidRuntime(361):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-01 02:47:58.195: E/AndroidRuntime(361):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thanks for help.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentIntent required

Comment: but I don't understand yet...

Comment: Notifications on Android 4.0+ (I think, might be 3.0+) require that you provide a pending intent so the user can click-through your notification to something

Comment: Uncomment your buider.setContentIntent(pi);